# Delphi threading

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2009

I need to start a thread in Delphi and use following code for that:

```
function ThreadFunc(tp: PThreadParams): Integer;
var
    I: Integer;
begin
    OutputDebugString(PChar('ThreadFunc, 1'));
    for I := 0 to 10000 do
    begin
        if (I MOD 100) = 0 then
        begin
                OutputDebugString(PChar('Sample Delphi DLL ' + IntToStr(I)));
        end;

    end;

    Dispose(tp);
end;

procedure RunThread;
var
tp : PThreadParams;
Thread : THandle;
ThreadID : Cardinal;
ExitCode : Cardinal;
begin
    New(tp);

    OutputDebugString(PChar('RunThread, 1'));

    Thread := BeginThread(nil, 0, @ThreadFunc, tp, 0, ThreadID);

    OutputDebugString(PChar('RunThread, 2. ThreadID: ' + IntToStr(ThreadID)));

    WaitForSingleObject(Thread, INFINITE);

    GetExitCodeThread(Thread, ExitCode);

    CloseHandle(Thread);
end;
```

When I run RunThread, the log file contains entries

> RunThread, 1
>
> RunThread, 2. ThreadID: ...

but no log output from `ThreadFunc`.

How should I change this code in order for the actual thread function (`ThreadFunc`) to be executed?

Comment: Why not use TThread? Makes it quite easy to implement threads.

Comment: Does it work in a "headless" (without GUI) environment? I need to start the thread in a DLL.

Comment: +1 for GolezTrol. Yes, it does.  If you wish to try an fix your example, try using the stdcall calling convention for the thread function.

Comment: Yes, one wonders why you don't just use `TThread`.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes, it really works, thanks. Please submit this statement as an answer and then I'll mark the question as answered.

Comment: I'd say for use threads one better to use AsyncCall or OTL. TThread is not adding much really. @Dmitry check http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/asynccalls-29-asynchronous-function-calls/ and http://otl.17slon.com/

Comment: @Martin - stdcall seems not correct here. That is not Win32 API (CreateThread) http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TThreadFunc http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.BeginThread
But personally i'd check if the thread was created suspended and need to be resumed.

Comment: No, `stdcall` would be wrong here. `BeginThread` takes a `TThreadFunc`. Which is not `stdcall`.

Comment: @Arioch'The - that is often 'very difficult', (again, trying not to use the 'i' word:).  Returning objects to the thread that created them is often an unreasonable overhead. For example, You may have no idea which of several threadpool threads created the object, or even if those threads still exist.  The originating threads would have to incorporate a return mechanism, maybe a queue instance added to every comms object and a 'returnToSender()' method - a pile of overhead.  The originator often does not want the objects back - it's busy making new ones.  OTOH, you could just free() them:)

Comment: @MArtin deleted comment, it was highly hypothetical

Comment: @Arioch'The - pity - I was just reading it <g>

Comment: I usually try to dodge such issues anyway.  I tend to use object pools, loaded up at startup, and just circulate objects from the pool, through threads and queues, and finally back to the pool again.  This means that I don't have to create or free any inter-thread comms objects during the app run.   I haven't seen any thread-local heap storage but, as I have never found the need for such a thing, (or indeed, any thread-local storage), I haven't looked too hard :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use TThread? Makes it quite easy to implement threads. ;-)

Comment: TThread class requires including a huge Classes.pas unit which in its turn requires other huge units. To create a small console application or a service application, BeginThread is more then enough. It is quite straightforward, and the author's code is mostly correct. I suspect that the problem is not with the threads, but with OutputDebugString, which is a quite obscure function. For example, I do not like to use the OutputDebugString.

Comment: The author's log has shown "Sample Delphi DLL". It tells that the author was writing a DLL, which is supposed to be small. That's why adding TThread from Classes.pas, thus significantly bloating the DLL size is not a good idea.

Comment: DLL's don't need to be any smaller than executables, and once you start writing actual functionality, you may very well use other classes from that unit too. After all, most people use Delphi for the RTL&VCL, not just for the Pascal syntax. Besides, a new DLL project includes Classes by default and a release build of it will be less than 1MB, even in the latest Delphi versions.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have checked everything again, including the calling convention, and have found out that the author's code is correct except the undefined return value. To the contrary, the TThread handles these return values automatically. On the other hand, Delphi compiler gives a warning on undefined return. So there is no evidence that TThread is much more human-error-resistant ;-)))

Answer (score 0):

### On The OutputDebugString

The problem in your case is probably with the OutputDebugString, and how Delphi IDE handles it. There is no problem with your thread. It runs properly. The only drawback with it is that ThreadFunc must return a value, which it does not in your case. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736(v=vs.85).aspx  (just return zero - the simplest case).

To check whether Delphi handles OutputDebugString properly or not, use an alternative application to display debug messages.

Exit Delphi, get DebugView from Windows Sysinternals at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx , run it, and while it is running, also run your application (just make sure that Delphi is not running).

In the DebugView log, you will see something like that:

```
[8484] RunThread, 1
[8484] RunThread, 2. ThreadID: 8388
[8484] ThreadFunc, 1
[8484] Sample Delphi DLL 0
[8484] Sample Delphi DLL 100
[8484] Sample Delphi DLL 200
<<< 96 lines skipped >>>
[8484] Sample Delphi DLL 9900
[8484] Sample Delphi DLL 10000
```

OutputDebugString is too obscure to rely on it. Just simpler methods to ensure that your thread is running, e.g. create a file or invoke a beep. So, the idea is, if DebugView doesn't help, just OutputDebugString from your thread and use other method do ensure that the thread is running. For example, add the following string to the beginning of your ThreadFunc:

```
MessageBox(0, 'Thread Text', 'Thread Caption', MB_OK);
```

Run your application. If you will see the message dialog, then your thread is running OK.

### On The Calling Convention

The calling convention (stdcall vs register) is not an issue here. Your code is correct in that sense. Look for the implementation of the BeginThread function in your System.pas (and for the definition of TThreadFunc, if it exists).

You didn’t mention what version of Delphi did you use, or maybe you are using other compatible compiler - this might have affected the types, but the probability of this is extremely low. Delphi 10.2 uses the ThreadWrapper function to pass it to Windows API CreateThread(). This ThreadWrapper is defined with “stdcall” calling convention, as required by Win32 specification, since it is directly passed to CreateThread() which runs is. The ThreadWrapper in its turn, calls you TThreadFunc which has register calling convention. The TThreadFunc is defined just the following way (plain and simple):

```
TThreadFunc = function(Parameter: Pointer): Integer;
```

So, as the code above have demonstrated, your ThreadFunc must match exactly the declaration of TThreadFunc. It does not have to be the “stdcall” like some people say in the comments. If your version of Delphi doesn’t have the TThreadFunc in the System.pas, look for the type required for the third parameter of BeginThread to make sure that everything is correct.

If you have compiler option “Typed @ operator” turned ON (which is OFF by default), and if the issue would have been in the calling convention mismatch, the compiler would have given an error. I suggest to always check the “Typed @ operator” option ON. Alternatively, add the {$T+} before your CreateThread call (or better in the beginning of the file). So you will make sure that there is no mismatch.

As I have explained, things have shown that the calling convention is not an issue here, and everything is correct in your code. If the calling convention would have been inappropriate, the ThreadFunc would have run anyway until the end, since doesn’t need any parameters until exit (Dispose(tp)), so there would have been an Access Violation error AFTER executing all the OutputDebugString calls – either on Dispose(tp) or on exit from ThreadFunc. You would have seen the output in the debugger and AFTER THAT got an Access Violation. Since there were no Access Violation - everything is OK with the calling convention.